# Android App crashing due to thread

Tags: java, android, multithreading, crash

I'm trying to make my first activity sleep for 5 seconds and then start a new activity but when I'm testing the application. The app is crashing. 
Here is my logcat

```
06-03 12:40:28.915: E/AndroidRuntime(1480):     at android.app.Instrumentation.checkStartActivityResult(Instrumentation.java:1618)
06-03 12:40:28.915: E/AndroidRuntime(1480):     at android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1417)
06-03 12:40:32.655: I/Choreographer(1480): Skipped 56 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
06-03 12:40:33.675: I/Process(1480): Sending signal. PID: 1480 SIG: 9
```

And below is my code.

```
           Thread timer = new Thread(){
    public void run(){
        try{
            sleep(5000);
        Intent openStartingPoint = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Menu.class);
            startActivity(openStartingPoint);
            finish();
        }   
        catch(InterruptedException e){

            e.printStackTrace();        

        }


    }


    };

timer.start();

}
```

Comment: http://developer.android.com/training/articles/perf-anr.html. using sleep inside a thread is a bad design. Check the link foe details. use a handler or runOnUiThread

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may use this code, it may help u..

```
  Thread timer = new Thread(){
public void run(){
    try{
        sleep(5000);
        MainActivity.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {                                 
             Intent openStartingPoint = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Menu.class);
             MainActivity.this.startActivity(openStartingPoint);
             MainActivity.this.finish();
           });

    }

    }   
    catch(InterruptedException e){

        e.printStackTrace();        

    }


}


    };

timer.start();

}
```